# How Do I Texture Curves Using Generated Textures?

Tags: bezier-curves

So I've been trying to texture this thing for the past month or so and I've made no progress at all. I'm trying to keep the bezier curve because it makes animating it much easier but I'm trying to add a texture. I tried using generated textures but it ended up looking like a weird and badly warped image of the texture I was trying to use. I want the image to display as if it were lain on top of the image and not stretched around. I was considering exporting a texture map but that seems to require a UV which requires it be a mesh, which is not what I want to use. And I don't know why but it started rendering wrong
[image]

As you can see, in the render it has a much less curved object rendered. I've really no idea what I'm doing wrong; help?

Comment: what is the animation that is easier when it is a curve? It might be you can convert it to a mesh for texturing and use something else to get the animation effect.

Comment: Well the way I animate I have to move the nodes around because my characters don't have rigid bodies all the time. So when they swing around their arms they tend to turn into shapeless blobs for a bit. I was considering turning it to a mesh and doing each frame but then I'd end up back where I started, doing each part of the animation frame by frame. With a mesh there are a gazillion more smaller nodes.

Comment: Don't needlessly convert to mesh just for texturing unless necessary. What is the texture you want to overlay and why isn't it working? Most of the time using either *Generated* or *Object* texture coordinates should suffice

Comment: I'm trying to put this one: https://i.imgur.com/3d7K6YJ.png but minus the legs. For some reason when it comes up on there it just renders it blue with a few blocky patches that are darker and that's it.